# Having two @interfaces in the same .h file

Tags: objective-c, facebook, interface, header, duplicates

I am making a photo upload to Facebook app and I think I need two @interfaces in my .h file for my View Controller.

Here is my ViewController.h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,   UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
UIImagePickerController *bailey;
UIImagePickerController *baileys;
UIImage *image;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}
-  (IBAction)TakePhoto;
-  (IBAction)ChooseExisting;
@end
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {   SLComposeViewController       *slComposeViewController;
UIImage *image; }
- (IBAction)ShareFB;
@end
```

When I try to build this code on to my iPhone or a Emulator it says

```
/Users/Condrum/Desktop/project/myApp/myApp/FirstViewController.h:21:1: Duplicate interface definition for class 'FirstViewController'
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

-Condrum.

Comment: Why do you have two interfaces of the same name? Either have two different names or put everything in one definition.

Comment: BTW, I'd encourage you to adopt Cocoa [method naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF), e.g. `takePhoto`, `chooseExisting`, and `shareFB` rather than `TakePhoto`, `ChooseExisting`, and `ShareFB`.

Comment: Thanks for the Method Naming Conventions advice, I will take them on board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern is to put a single public interface into the .h file:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

// in here put those public properties and method declarations that
// other classes need to have access to

@end
```

Then put the second `@implementation` in the .m file as a [private class extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3):

```
@interface FirstViewController () <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,   UINavigationControllerDelegate>

// in here, place those private properties and instance variables that
// only this class needs to be aware of

@end
```

Note, this second interface uses the `()` syntax, which indicates that the interface is extending a previously defined interface.

But there's no point in putting both of those interfaces in the same .h file (why have two interfaces; it would be more logical to combine them into one). The primary value of the private class extension is you can extend your interface with details that only the implementation cares about, and avoid cluttering your nice simple public interface. So generally, keep public interface in the .h file, and move the private stuff into the class extension in the .m file.

For more information, see [Class Extensions Extend the Internal Implementation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3).

Comment: Thanks Rob! It worked great and I am now able to continue, but I may need to implement a Third @interface later, how would I do that?

Comment: @Condrum Another extension. Or possibly a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW2). It is pretty rare that you'd need yet another `@interface` (I'm fascinated by why you think you need a third one), but it can be done.

Comment: I need a third @interface because I needed one to take the photo a second to upload to Facebook and a Third to upload to Twitter, I may be able to integrate them but I am waiting till I get Facebook down pat before I continue to Twitter.

Comment: @Condrum But why would that require a separate interface? Why not add the new methods/properties to the existing interface? The only time I'd use a third `@interface` is if adding a category to an existing class I didn't have access to source code, or where I needed some special interface in special cases (like <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>). Otherwise, I'm just adding to the existing interfaces. Do whatever you want, but IMHO, multiple interfaces should be used sparingly.

Comment: ok in future I will try rather to integrate them then to add a new interface. Thanks for all the help.